# React-native key board events

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am writing a react native app and need to implement keyboard events inside components.

I tried with following code and did not success.

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

export default class KeyEvent {
  static onKeyDownListener(cb) {
    KeyEvent.removeKeyDownListener();
    console.log('Key Down');
    this.listenerKeyDown = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onKeyDown', cb);
  }

  static removeKeyDownListener() {
    if (this.listenerKeyDown) {
      this.listenerKeyDown.remove();
    }
  }

  static onKeyUpListener(cb) {
    console.log('Key up');
    KeyEvent.removeKeyUpListener();
    this.listenerKeyUp = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onKeyUp', cb);
  }

  static removeKeyUpListener() {
    if (this.listenerKeyUp) {
      this.listenerKeyUp.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Call inside componentDidMount function relevant component as follows.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    // if you want to react to keyDown 
    KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyCode) => {
      console.log(`Key code pressed: ${keyCode}`);
    });

    // if you want to react to keyUp 
    KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyCode) => {
      console.log(`Key code pressed: ${keyCode}`);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log('componentWillUnmount');
    // if you are listening to keyDown 
    KeyEvent.removeKeyDownListener();

     // if you are listening to keyUp 
    KeyEvent.removeKeyUpListener();
  }
```

Can anyone help me to fix this or suggest any other way of doing this. I need to press a button on enter key down.

Answer (score 3):

As per react native doc, you can attach below events to keyboard.

```
keyboardWillShow
keyboardDidShow
keyboardWillHide
keyboardDidHide
keyboardWillChangeFrame
keyboardDidChangeFrame
```

So if you want pressed key event then you need to attach event to input field like below.

```
<TextInput
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}
    placeholder="Enter text here..."
/>

handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    if(e.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
        dismissKeyboard();
    }
},
```

Comment: I need to identify up, down, left, right, back and enter keydown events. As i understood this is related to display keyboard.

Comment: No these are related to input field.

Comment: attach onKeyPress event to input field you will get code of pressed button.

Comment: this is the reference link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onkeypress

Comment: Thank you. This is for TextField. Any idea of using it for button press event  on enter key down event.

Comment: Yes, without TextField you won't get keyborad on your screen to type.

Comment: My app is not only for mobile, It should work for Desktop PCs also. That's why I need that functionality.

Comment: Whatever it is, you should catch the key pressed event. then only you would recognise pressed key.

Comment: `onKeyPress` is for ios only. I think the question is after an android implementation.